# Show brand on woocommerce product page

Tags: woocommerce

i would like to have woocommerce display the brand of the product under product information on each product

is that possible?

Thanks in advance 
Morten

wordpress 3.9.1
woocommerce  2.1.10

Answer (score 1):

The following will work on a WooCommerce single product page.

The easiest way is to create a WooCommerce Product Category called "Brands" and list your brands as sub-categories.

-Brands
--Apple
--Microsoft
--Google

You'd check the brand category "Apple" to your product, for example. Skip checking "Brands" however.

Next you need a hook that will display the checked sub-category of "Brands" under you product.

One such hook is: `woocommerce_after_single_product()`

There are others [here](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/hooks/) - the WooCommerce hook reference

In your functions.php file or plugin, add the following code.

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_single_product', 'my_woocommerce_after_single_product' );
function my_woocommerce_after_single_product () {

    global $product;

    $taxonomy = 'product_cat';
    $slug = 'brand'; //Or whatever the slug of "Brand" is

    $term = get_term_by('slug', $slug, $taxonomy);

    //Gets the ID of the Parent category
    $term_id = $term->term_id;

    //Get the Child terms
    $brand_terms = wp_get_post_terms( $product->id, $taxonomy, array("fields" => "all") );

        foreach ($brand_terms as $brand_item) {

            // Hunt out the child term that is a child of the parent
            if ( $brand_item->parent == $term_id ) {

                //Get the name of the brand
                $brand = $brand_item->name;

                break; //Assumes you've only assigned one Brand
            }

        }

        echo '<p>The Brand is: ' . $brand; //Apple or Microsoft or Google...
}
```

---

(If it works, please mark it as "Answered")